# Representation of an involution operator with an operator matrix

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, proof-explanation

Let $A$ be a bounded linear operator on a complex Hilbet space $H$ such that 
$$A^2=I.$$

> Why there exists a bounded operator $T$ such that $A$ will be equal to the operator matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
> I&T \\
> 0&-I
> \end{pmatrix}$? Is it possible to find the expression of $T$?

This property is used in the proof of the following theorem in [this paper](https://rmmc.eas.asu.edu/rmj/rmjVOLS2/vol45/vol45-4/abu.pdf)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can decompose $H$ as $$\tag1 H=\ker(A-I)\oplus \ker(A-I)^\perp.$$ Let $P$ be the orthogonal projection onto $\ker (A-I)$. For any $x\in H$ we have $Px\in \ker (A-I)$, so
$$
APx=Px. 
$$
Thus $$\tag2AP=P.$$ If we write $A$ as a block matrix with respect to the decomposition $(1)$,  we have
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} PAP&PA(I-P)\\ (I-P)AP&(I-P)A(I-P)\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
From $(2)$ we have that $PAP=P$, $(I-P)AP=0$, and
$$\tag3
(I-P)A(I-P)=(I-P)A=A-PA. 
$$
Since $A^2-I=0$, for any $x\in H$
$$\tag4
0=(A^2-I)x=(A-I)(A+I)x.
$$
That is, $(A+I)x\in\ker(A-I)=PH$. Thus
$P(A+I)=A+I$, and so $$\tag5 A-PA=-(I-P).$$
Now, using $(3)$ and $(5)$,
$$\tag6
(I-P)A(I-P)=(I-P)A=-(I-P).
$$

So the matrix representation of $A$ becomes
$$\tag7
A=\begin{bmatrix} P&PA(I-P)\\ 0&-(I-P)\end{bmatrix} .
$$
As $P$ acts as the identity on $\ker(A-I)$ and $I-P$ acts as the identity on $\ker(A-I)^\perp$, we can write $(7)$ as
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}I&PA(I-P)\\0&-I\end{bmatrix} . 
$$

Comment: Thank you Professor for your answer. Just I don't understand how you obtained the following expression $$
A=\begin{bmatrix} PAP&PA(I-P)\\ (I-P)AP&(I-P)A(I-P)\end{bmatrix}. 
$$?

Comment: Well, if you are going to be talking about block operators, you need to understand block operators. Given a projection $P$, you can write $$A=PAP+PA(I-P)+(I-P)AP+(I-P)A(I-P).$$ Then you check that, both with respect to addition and multiplication, this decomposition behaves exactly like the $2\times 2$ matrix above.

Comment: I believe there is a mistake in the relation $(3)$. It says that $(I-P)A(I-P) = A(I-P)$ which would imply $PA(I-P) = 0$ and hence $A = \begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ 0 & -I\end{bmatrix}$, which clearly doesn't have to be the case.

Instead, we can notice that $0 = A^2 = (A-I)(A+I)$ so for any $x \in H$ we have $(A+I)x \in \ker(A-I)$ which means
$P(A+I) = A+I$. This can be rewritten as $(I-P)(A+I) = 0$ so 
$$(I-P)A(I-P) = (I-P)(A+I)(I-P)-(I-P) = -(I-P).$$

Comment: Good catch! Thanks for noticing. I have edited the answer as suggested.